# Assistance with javascript function

Tags: javascript, checkbox, hyperlink

I am trying to write code to activate a hyperlink if all checkboxes are checked.  Below is the code written I have written that will produce the checkboxes. How do I add the capability to enable the hyperlink button when all the checkboxes are checked ?

````
```<head> 
    <title>Check/Uncheck the checkbox using JavaScript</title> 
```</head> 

```<body> 
    <center> 
        <h1 style="color:green">To ensure HIPAA compliance and follow company policy:</h1> 
        <h2>Check the checkbox in order to continue</h2> 
        <form> 
            <div> 
                <input type="button" onclick="checkAll()" value="CHECK ALL"> 
                      </div> 
            <div> 
                <label> 
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check3"> I agree to use no parts of my actual name in ```my screen name. 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            <div> 
                <label> 
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check3"> I agree to not to use open room chat to share ```personal information, knowing that open room chat is visible by all who enter the room. 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            <div> 
                <label> 
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check3"> I agree to provide all personal identifiable ```information to the intake professional and therapist. 
                </label> 
        </div> 
            <div> 
                <label> 
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check3"> I agree to refrain from providing personal ```information of my own or the therapist to other individuals in the lobby. 
                </label> 
            </div> 
        </form> 
    </center> 
```</body> 
```<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //create function of check/uncheck box 
    function checkAll() { 
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.check3'); 
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
            inputs[i].checked = true; 
        } 
    } 
    window.onload = function() { 
        window.addEventListener('load', checkAll, false); 
    } 
```</script> 
  <input type="button" onclick="(https://app.sococo.com/meet/5725dc80632b143d168fbf3155bcddf0)" ```value="Start Your Journey"> 
```</html>
````

Comment: Do you need a function for individual checkbox to check if all checkboxes are checked before activating the link?

Comment: Yes, I need it to basically check for all boxes to be checked and the button to take them to another webpage, but the button only needs to be active if they have checked all the boxes, no tpart of the list